# find $\lim_n\frac{a^\frac1n}{n+1}+\frac{a^\frac 2n}{n+\frac 12}+...+\frac{a^\frac nn}{n+\frac 1n}$ using Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Here is the question:

prove that $S_n=\frac{a^\frac1n}{n+1}+\frac{a^\frac 2n}{n+\frac 12}+...+\frac{a^\frac nn}{n+\frac 1n}$ is convergent for $a>0$ then find its limit.

My attempt: If we accept that $S_n$ is convergent then by multiplying each sides by $a^\frac1n$ have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(a^\frac 1n-1)S_n=n\frac{-a^\frac 1n}{n+1}+na^\frac 2n(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+\frac 12})+...+na^\frac nn(\frac1{n+\frac 1n}-\frac 1{n+\frac 1{n-1}})+n\frac{a^\frac{n+1}n}{n+\frac 1n}$$
so $$\lim S_n=\frac{a-1}{\ln a}$$

(I think we should assume $a\neq 1)$

However usually people calculate such limits using Riemann integral. I would like to use Riemann integral to find the value of the limit.

Thank you kindly for your help.

---

Edit:
$n\frac{-a^\frac 1n}{n+1}+n\frac{a^\frac{n+1}n}{n+\frac 1n}=n\frac{-a^\frac 1n}{n+1}+na^\frac 2n(\frac{1}{n+\frac 12}-\frac{1}{n+\frac 12})+...+na^\frac nn(\frac1{n+\frac 1{n-1}}-\frac 1{n+\frac 1{n-1}})+n\frac{a^\frac{n+1}n}{n+\frac 1n}\leq n(a^\frac1n-1)S_n\leq n\frac{-a^\frac 1n}{n+1}+na^\frac 2n(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1})+...+na^\frac nn(\frac1{n+\frac 1n}-\frac 1{n+\frac 1{n}})+n\frac{a^\frac{n+1}n}{n+\frac 1n}=n\frac{-a^\frac 1n}{n+1}+n\frac{a^\frac{n+1}n}{n+\frac 1n}$

Comment: "...so $\;\lim...$ ..." ?? How?

Comment: @Timbuc : well $\lim n(a^\frac 1n-1)=\ln a$ and all the right hand side limits equal $0$ except for $\lim n\frac{-a^\frac 1n}{n+1}=-1$ and $\lim n\frac{a^\frac {n+1}n}{n+\frac 1n}=a$ . Right?

Comment: I don't get it, really: are you using arithmetic of limits on the right to reach the answer? Because it certainly looks like you are, yet you can **not** do that without further justification as the number of summands on the RHS depends on $\;n\;$ itself...like saying that the limit of $\;\overbrace{\frac1n+\frac1n+\ldots+\frac1n}^{n\;\text{times}}\;$ is zero because every summands tends to zero. This is wrong, of course...what's the justification for yours?

Comment: @Timbuc I think you are right. I edited my attempt. Maybe using sqeeze theorem could help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sum

$$S_n = \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{a^{{i\over n}}}{n + \frac{1}{i}} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{a^{{i\over n}}}{1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{n}{i}}$$

is not quite a Riemann-sum since the summand is not on the form $\frac{1}{n}f\left({i\over n}\right)$ for some ($n$-independent) function $f$. However, it it very close to the Riemann-sum

$$\tilde{S}_n =  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}a^{{i\over n}}$$

which converges to the integral $\int_0^1a^{x}{\rm d}x$. The difference between the two sums $\tilde{S}_n$ and $S_n$ satisfy

$$0 \leq \tilde{S}_n - S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a^{{i\over n}}}{n}\frac{1}{1 + ni} \leq \frac{1}{n}\tilde{S}_n$$

and since $\tilde{S}_n$ converges we have $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} S_n - \tilde{S}_n = 0$ and it follows that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{a^{{i\over n}}}{n + \frac{1}{i}} = \int_0^1 a^x {\rm d}x = \frac{a-1}{\log(a)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well to convert to Riemann integral, you expect $i/n\to x$ and $1/n\to dx$. Then you just play around:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a^{i/n}}{n+1/i}=\sum_{i=1}^n dx \frac{a^{x}}{1+1/(xn^2)}\to \int_0^1  a^x dx$$

What Riemann sum actually does is just limit the interval width $dx$ to zero, and covers the $x$ uniformly and continuously across the available range from $1/n$ to $n/n$. You start by isolating the $1/n$ term in front and check if the rest can be expressed with $i/n$.

The only mystery is the $1/(xn^2)$. This one you can just eliminate in the limit, because when $n\to \infty$, it is negligible compared to $1$ (it's actually better to leave it as $1/(in)$ because $in>n\to\infty$).

In the most standard textbook examples, there are no "extra" terms where $n$ is left standing alone. In that case, when you convert to $dx$ and $x$, just replace $\sum$ with $\int$. But here, there was something left, but fortunately went to zero in the limit.

Strictly speaking, we should not have done that without a proof (limit each term separately and then take the Riemann limit afterwards) but it worked out fine :)

Comment: Thanks, But How? why $\sum_{i=1}^n dx \frac{a^{x}}{1+1/(xn^2)}\to \int_0^1  a^x dx$?

Comment: Edited, I hope it helps.