# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^\frac{1}{n}}{n+1}+\frac{2^\frac{2}{n}}{n+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}+...+\frac{2^\frac{n}{n}}{n+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Find the limit by using Riemann integrals of suitably chosen function(s): $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2^\frac{1}{n}}{n+1}\right) + \left(\frac{2^\frac{2}{n}}{n+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right) +\dots + \left(\frac{2^\frac{n}{n}}{n+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)$

I know that with Riemann sums it's best to find the limit summation $(\Delta x) (f(x_i))$. So I changed the question to look like a summation.

$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{2^{\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}n}{n+ \left(\frac{1}{i}\right)}\right)$$

However, if I set the integral I am left with some ns in the denominator that I am not sure what to do with:
$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{2^xnx}{nx+1}\right) \,dx $

Am I even approaching this question in the right way? If so, what do I do with the $n$s?
Any guidance would be helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find $\lim_n\frac{a^\frac1n}{n+1}+\frac{a^\frac 2n}{n+\frac 12}+...+\frac{a^\frac nn}{n+\frac 1n}$ using Riemann integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343082/find-lim-n-fraca-frac1nn1-fraca-frac-2nn-frac-12-fraca-fra) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cfrac%7B2%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bi%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%7D%7Bn%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bi%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3ARiemann%20integral&p=1). ...

Comment: (cont.) FYI, a related question is [Limit of summation $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\dfrac{{{2^{\frac{k}{n}}}}}{{n + \frac{1}{k}}}}$](/q/2042749). Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: The expression that looks "like a summation" omits any mention of the index *i* in the denominator after the summation sign.

Comment: Buncha typos / minor algebraic errors in your attempt to convert this to sigma notation.